# Why key isn't created in defaultdict.get()?

Tags: python, collections

When I try code below, I see strange behavior of `defaultdict` from `collections`.

```
>>> import collections as c
>>> d = c.defaultdict(int) # empty dict
>>> d['a'] += 1 # generate default value 0 and assingment adding 1
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'a': 1})
>>> d['b'] # generate default value without assignment
0 # returning default value
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'a': 1, 'b': 0})
>>> d.get('c') # not adding key to dict
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'a': 1, 'b': 0})
```

So why `dict[key]` generating key with default value and `.get(key)` not?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict `__missing__`

Comment: Because the get() function only returns exiting elements. In your case, the  key c is not  in dictionary. Other hand, when you  use defaultdict, it creates an empty list (in your case 0) when key is not encountered, for this reason d['c'] is 0.